# User control properties value not set

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have this user control:

```
public Guid ItemID
{
        get
        {
            return this.ViewState.GetValue<Guid>("UserControl.ItemID", Guid.Empty);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["UserControl.ItemID"] = value;
        }
}

public override void DataBind()
{
    base.DataBind();
    this.ConfigureControls();
}

private void ConfigureControls()
{
    // I am using ItemID here
}
```

My problem here is when I put a breakpoint on the Configure Controls and on the Get Setter of the Item ID property, it goes first on the Configure controls resulting the ItemID to be null.

What can I do so that my property would be initialize first?

Comment: `ViewState.GetValue` must be an extension method from you.

Comment: Your code needs to call `ItemID = someGuid` before `ConfigureControls()`.

Comment: @DavidArno - do I need to do that on the usercontrol itself? or on the page consuming it?